# COLMAP installation failing on: The string is missing the terminator: "

Tags: powershell, batch-file, terminator

I'm trying to install COLMAP using the following process

```
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
cd vcpkg
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
.\vcpkg install colmap[cuda]:x64-windows
```

When running the .bat I'm getting this error:

```
The string is missing the terminator: ".
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

The bat looks like this:

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "& {& \"%~dp0scripts\bootstrap.ps1\" %*}"
```

A file called bootstrap.ps1 does indeed live in .\scripts

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is coming from the Powershell execution.

Comment: Thanks - can you kindly please give more information and suggest a fix?

Comment: Can't fix what I cannot see.

Comment: The number of `"` characters is unbalanced. I'd add an extra one at the end - but with no confidence that this would achieve a cure.

Comment: This installation issue caused by using the wrong syntax in a batch file interpreted by the *Windows Command Processor* only used to start *PowerShell* for the execution of a PowerShell script should be reported to the author of the *GitHub* repository [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) as otherwise the next user might have the same installation problem depending on the the path `%~dp0` references on the users Windows PC. You have not posted the full path of the directory containing `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`, i.e. what is the full folder path of folder `vcpkg` on your PC.

Comment: The *Windows Command Processor* supports only `"` for marking the beginning and the end of an argument string in comparison to *PowerShell* supporting multiple [quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules). It is not possible to escape `"` inside an argument string enclosed in `"` for being interpreted as literal character by the *Windows Command Processor*. The quoting rule for the *Windows Command Processor* is very simple.

Comment: If quotation is currently not active the first `"` marks the beginning of a quoted string (with the one exception that there is left not `^`) and the next found `"` or end of line marks the end of a quoted string. That's it. The second line is for `cmd.exe` as list of following argument strings: `powershell.exe`, `-NoProfile`, `-ExecutionPolicy`, `Bypass`, `"& {& \"`, ``%~dp0scripts\bootstrap.ps1\``, `" %*}"`. What is important know is to which strings `%~dp0` and `%*` expand on [Windows Command Processor parsing the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/).

Comment: We know from your description that `%*` is replaced by an empty string because of the batch file is run by you without any arguments. But we don't know the full directory path referenced with `%~dp0`. If that folder path contains for example the character `&`, `cmd.exe` would interpret that ampersand in folder path as unconditional command operator because of being not enclosed in a double quoted argument string as required by `cmd.exe` on a file/folder name (or any other argument string) containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<>|``.

Comment: *PowerShell* is in this case run by `cmd.exe` with `powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "& {& \"C:\Temp\Development ` and the rest is missing as there is next `& Test 100%(!)\scripts\bootstrap.ps1\" }"` character in folder path and therefore `cmd.exe` interprets the rest of the command line as second command to execute after `powershell.exe` by running `Test` with `100%(!)\scripts\bootstrap.ps1\" }"` as arguments. What exactly is the problem with the wrong coded command line in the batch file `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat` on your PC cannot be determined by us with the provided info.

Comment: A solution __could be__ the modification of the batch file `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat` to the single command line `@powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0scripts\bootstrap.ps1" %*`. Another solution __could be__ running directly in the command prompt window in the directory `vcpkg` simply `powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%CD%\scripts\bootstrap.ps1"`. As a user of this package please report the problem with the explanation (link to this page) and the working solution and your folder path to the author of the GitHub repository.

Comment: There was a "&" in my file path, thank you, removing that fixed the issue!  You were very helpful, thanks for the long reply, I learned a lot.